# Bash script doesn't read input

Tags: bash, shell, shell-script, input

I have a script that is suppose to run a command in the background, and it does that. The problem is that when the script comes upon a read command, it doesn't pause and accept input. Here it is:

```
printf "Where is yo music?: "
read musicPath

cd $musicPath
ls | while read currentSong;do
  seconds=`mdls "$currentSong"|sed -n '20p'|awk '{print $3}'|cut -d. -f1`
  hours=$((seconds / 3600))
  seconds=$((seconds % 3600))
  minutes=$((seconds / 60))
  seconds=$((seconds % 60))
  echo "Song: $currentSong"
  echo "Length: $hours:$minutes:$seconds"
  afplay "$currentSong"&
  printf "yes (y), no (n), or maybe (m): "
  read choice
  case $choice in
    y)
      mkdir ../Yes
      mv "$currentSong" ../Yes
    ;;
    n)
      mkdir ../No
      mv "$currentSong" ../No
    ;;
    m)
      mkdir ../Maybe
      mv "$currentSong" ../
    ;;
    *)
      echo "Invalid option! Continuing..."
    ;;
  esac
  kill $!
done
```

Comment: in bash, you can provide the prompt in the read command itself: `read -p "where is yo music? " musicPath`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There are numerous issues with that script, but the one thats causing your specific issue is because you're reading from a pipe (the output of `ls`).

#### 1. [Don't parse `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)

Use this instead

```
for currentSong in *; do
  ...
done
```

Aside from the numerous reasons you shouldnt parse `ls`, the issue you're seeing is because STDIN is connected to the output of `ls`. So when you issue a `read`, it can't read from the terminal because STDIN isn't connected to the terminal.

#### 2. [Use more quotes](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Practices/#Quoting)

You've got a fair amount of quotes spread around, but still missing some. Mainly just on the `cd`.

```
cd "$musicPath"
```

also

```
case "$choice"
```

#### 3. [Don't use backticks](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/082)

Using backticks is ok sometimes. I frequently use them on the command line as it faster to type than `$()`. But for scripting, it's good practice to use `$()` instead.

```
seconds="$(mdls "$currentSong"|sed -n '20p'|awk '{print $3}'|cut -d. -f1)"
```

#### 4. mkdir

Your `mkdir` will generate an (harmless but noisy) error if the directories already exist. Add a `-p` in there which will cause the `mkdir` to silently do nothing if it already exists

```
mkdir -p ../Yes
```

---

*Yes, there are a lot of pitfalls with bash. Not trying to be harsh, just trying to break bad habits.
Have fun :-)*

Comment: Thanks for all of the tips! I love this stuff, so no worries. Always love learning new things (: